# Laravel File::mimeType memory issues

Tags: php, laravel, mime-types

There is an issue with one of my jobs, where I'm using a code block

```
$mimeType = \File::mimeType($localFile); // $localFile - absolute path of the file
```

This brings an memory issues with message below

> local.ERROR: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 156161944 bytes) {"exception":"[object] (Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException(code: 1): Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 156161944 bytes) at /var/www/project/vendor/league/flysystem/src/Util/MimeType.php:209)

It's clear, that by increasing memory limit this issue will be resolved, but I'm looking for something more, let's say flexible or elegant way of detecting file mime type like I have done for file upload to s3 and avoids memory issues using below code

```
$disk = Storage::disk('s3');
$disk->put($path, fopen($localFile, 'r+'));
```

Is there any way to detect mime type without increasing memory limit?

Thanks

Comment: php default is `mime_content_type($localFile);` see [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mime-content-type.php)

Comment: @STA and it will not face to same issue ?

Comment: @Vald, I give you the default php function, if you face the same issue, then increse your memory size from php.ini . Otherwise you cant do that with php.

Comment: So, I think the issues is related to finding the mimeType https://github.com/thephpleague/flysystem/issues/1172 and I am trying to work out a better fix. Right now if I declare the mimetype as a config option it solves the issue, because it doesn't have to try to figure it out `Storage::put('directory/' . $filename, $contents, ['mimetype' => 'audio/mpeg']);`

Answer (score 2):

So it looks like the root cause is coming from the encoding of libmagic. For v1 of Flysystems(which laravel is currently using in V8) they added a dependency that you can use to get the mimetype by file type, which should resolve the issue.

Original Issue -
https://github.com/thephpleague/flysystem/issues/1172

Dependency -
https://github.com/thephpleague/mime-type-detection

So you would include the new detector and use one of the different types to get the mime type without relying on libmagic.

```
$detector = new \League\MimeTypeDetection\FinfoMimeTypeDetector();
$mimeType = $detector->detectMimeTypeFromPath($localFile);
Storage::put($path, $contents, ['mimetype' => $mimeType]);
```